# Tensorflow Lite input strings

Tags: android, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow-lite

I wanted to run a TfLite model on my android app to do some Natural Language Processing. I was wondering in what format would I have to taken in input for the TFLite model? I'm having trouble finding necessary documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of training a text classification model with TensorFlow Lite.
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_text_classification

And see this sample app on how to integrate the model to an Android app.
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/text_classification/android

TF Lite doesn't currently support raw text inputs. You will need to pre-process your text input into numbers (e.g. word embedding, tokenize etc.) then use them as model inputs.